# How to read large file to object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, memory

I'm working on a project where I need to extract data from each line in really large files (up to 5gb and 30 million lines). Right now I am able to load the and read the file, but once I get to about line 20 million I run out of memory and the browser crashes. Currently all the information is saved to one object (Data.GFF).

```
let lastLine = '';
const decoder = new TextDecoder();
const writableStream = new WritableStream({
  start(controller) {},
  async write(chunk, controller) {
    chunk = decoder.decode(chunk); //Unit8Array => text

    let lines = chunk.split(/\n/);
    delete chunk; //I think this frees a bit of memory

    lines[0] = lastLine + lines[0]; //last line is cutoff, add it to next chunk
    linesLength = lines.length - 1;
    switch(extension) {
      case 'gff':
      case 'gft':
      case 'gff3':
        lines.forEach(GFF); //extract data from each line
        break;
    }
    delete lines; //again -- I think this frees a bit of memory

    notification.innerHTML = `Loading... (${++chunkIndex})`;
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 0)); //allow HTML to load
  },
  close() {
    [lastLine].forEach(GFF); //read final line

    notification.remove();
  },
  abort(reason) {},
});

const stream = e.target.files[0].stream();
stream.pipeTo(writableStream);
```

I have tried using window[] to create a dynamic variable, but then it stores everything to the window and still crashed, same with eval() it just adds it to the window object. I'm hoping there is something that will work with any file size.

Comment: you should read the file [one line at a time](https://stackabuse.com/reading-a-file-line-by-line-in-node-js/) and also write it this way